# Logic issue to update text file - Java

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm having a logic issue to update a text file via user input.

I have a text file containing product information (ID;Name;Cost;Stock) :

```
001;Hand Soap;2.00;500
```

In order to add a product the user calls a function addProduct in order to either update a product if the product name already exists in the file or append to the text file if it does not yet exist. I'm unsure of two things : how to append only once (for the moment it's appending for every line it reads..) and how to deal with an empty text file.

This is how addProduct looks:

```
public void addProduct(Product product, int amountReceived) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    newProduct = product;
    String productParams = newProduct.getProduct();
    String productID = newProduct.getProductID();
    int productStock = newProduct.getProductStock();
    String productName = newProduct.getProductName();
    String tempFileName = "tempFile.txt";

    System.out.println("Attempting to Add Product : " + newProduct.getProduct());

    BufferedReader br = null;
    BufferedWriter bw = null;

    try {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(ProductMap.productFile);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        String line;
        StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder();

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Line : " + line);
            String [] productInfo = line.split(";");
            System.out.println("Added Product Info length : " + productInfo.length);
            if (productInfo.length > 0) {
                if (productInfo[1].equals(productName))
                {
                    System.out.println("Adding existing product");
                    System.out.println("Product Info : " + String.valueOf(productInfo[3]));
                    //line = line.replace(String.valueOf(productInfo), String.valueOf(productStock - amountSold));
                    productInfo[3] = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(productInfo[3]) + amountReceived);
                    String newLine = productInfo[0] + ";" + productInfo[1] + ";" + productInfo[2] + ";" + productInfo[3];
                    fileContent.append(newLine);
                    fileContent.append("\n");

                    System.out.println("Updated Product Info : " + String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(productInfo[3]) + amountReceived));
                    System.out.println("Line :" + newLine);
                } else {
                    fileContent.append(line);
                    fileContent.append("\n");
                    fileContent.append(productParams);
                    fileContent.append("\n");
                    //fileContent.append(productParams + "\n");
                    //System.out.println("Product Name : " + productInfo[1]);
                    //System.out.println("The full product info : " +productParams);
                }

            }
            br.readLine();
        }

        if (br.readLine() == null) {
            fileContent.append(productParams);
        }


        System.out.println("Product Updated File Contents : " + fileContent);
        FileWriter fstreamWrite = new FileWriter(ProductMap.productFile);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstreamWrite);
        System.out.println("File Content : " + fileContent);
        out.write(fileContent.toString());
        out.close();

        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a high level, a simple text file may not be the best choice for this use.  This implementation requires enough memory to hold the entire file.

If you only had additions and could just append to the file directly, things would be easier.  A database would seem to be the best choice.  Somewhere between a database and a simple text file, a [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) could help if the data could be written with standard lengths for each field.  Then you could overwrite a particular row rather than having to rewrite the whole file.

Given the constraints of the current setup, I can't think of a way around writing all the data each time the file is updated.

To get around the empty file problem, you could skip the else condition of the current loop So the new data would not be added to the fileContent StringBuffer.  Then when writing the data back out, you could either write the new data before or after the other information from the file.

Also, the readLine at the bottom of the loop is not needed.  Any row that is read at the bottom of the loop will be skipped over and not really processed when the read at the top of the loop gets the next line.